# Audio on the web page

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I am working on a project, and my current task is add a feature to listen audio file directly in the web page. What options do I have? All files are mp3, and the page contains about 15 audio files

Unfortunately, the flash player looks like only one possible solution and I just hope if somebody will give me a clue how to make the feature done without it.

Update: Thanks for the direction with audio tag!

Comment: In order to effectively answer this question, you will need to tell us what your supported browsers are. HTML5 audio tags are not yet universally supported.

Comment: oh sorry, I just forgot it. The feature should work on as many browsers as it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<audio>` tag!  Note that different browsers support different compression solutions. Currently OGG Vorbis seems to be the most appropriate format to convert the audio into.

Edit: I seems that some browsers support OGG and some browsers support MP3. If you can, have both versions available and upload both. Then, in the markup have a declaration that looks like this:

```
<audio controls autobuffer>
    <source src="audio.mp3" />
    <source src="audio.ogg" />
</audio>
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that native HTML5 audio will not work in all browsers (such as IE6, 7, and 8). Likewise, Flash audio will not work in mobile Safari. Your best bet for a production-grade solution is an audio abstraction framework that will use either HTML5 or Flash-based audio based on the client's browser. Fortunately, there is such a framework, based in jQuery, called [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org).

Answer (score 1):

Try the `audio` tag in html5

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp

http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/